# Unable to Load SDK Information Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-manager

I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (Version 15.5.7). I am coming from a corporate network and when I try to open the Android SDK Manager, I see the screenshot below with the error - "Loading SDK component information failed. Please retry".

When I connect my machine to a connection outside of our corporate network (on LTE hotspot), I am able to load and view that screen without problem.

I suspect our corporate firewall is blocking something. We tried tracing connections coming out of my machine while trying to open that screen and hitting retry. We were unable to see anything.

Does anyone know where I can find more detailed logs on this error on my side? Or what URL specifically it may be trying to reach out to? I need to know specifically which URL it's trying to access to get the networking folks to create the exception.

Thanks!

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: So did you find this: https://blog.xamarin.com/installing-xamarin-made-easy-offline-installation/

Comment: i didn't find that, but i found this.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server. Not helpful though because I need to be able to tell networking which URL exactly they want to set exception for on firewall. They're not going to open up all those URLs.

Comment: If corporate isn't going to allow access based on official Microsoft documentation, then tell your manager that you can't do your job.

Answer (score 16):

Change the repository to Google by clicking "settings icon" beside 'apply changes' button.